# How can I set a text left in a button with an image

Tags: button, text, tkinter, alignment

my problem ist to set the text alignment to the left side in a button.
The button is an image. With my code the text is set in the center.

```
root = tk.Tk()                                               
root.geometry('740x740+200+200') 

img = PhotoImage(file="/Users/my_name/Documents/Wing101 Beispiele/button-2.png") 

testBtn1=Button(root,  fg="white", image=img, text="TEST1",  compound=tk.CENTER, command=lambda: TestLogic(0)).place(x=400, y=200) 

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

See this amended code.

You need to add blank spaces to the right of your text. The amount of blank space to add will depend on the width of your `tk.Button`

I did tried adding the `justify="left"` option for `tk.Button` but did not find it helpful. Not sure why.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()                                               
root.geometry('740x740+200+200') 

img = tk.PhotoImage(file="/Users/my_name/Documents/Wing101 Beispiele/button-2.png") 

text="TEST1                                                                                         "
testBtn1=tk.Button(root,fg="blue",image=img,text=text,compound=tk.CENTER,
                   command=lambda: TestLogic(0)).place(x=400, y=200) 

root.mainloop()
```